# How to have virtualbox python bindings working with chosen Python version?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualbox, python-3.7, python-3.8

I'm using Python3 bindings for virtualbox (pyvbox). It works with the initial python3 version of my system which is 3.7. Now, I would like to use the very same bindings with python3.8. I have installed all needed python3.8 packages, but i get this error:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20191008] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import virtualbox
>>> _vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
m=VBoxPython3_8 x=No module named 'VBoxPython3_8'
m=VBoxPython3 x=No module named 'VBoxPython3'
m=VBoxPython x=/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxPython.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home//.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualbox/library_ext/vbox.py", line 22, in __init__
    manager = virtualbox.Manager()
  File "/home//.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualbox/__init__.py", line 145, in __init__
    self.manager = vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager(mtype, mparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 989, in __init__
    self.platform = PlatformXPCOM(dPlatformParams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/vboxapi/__init__.py", line 750, in __init__
    import xpcom.vboxxpcom
  File "/usr/lib/virtualbox/sdk/bindings/xpcom/python/xpcom/vboxxpcom.py", line 78, in <module>
    raise Exception('Cannot find VBoxPython module (tried: %s)' % (', '.join(_asVBoxPythons),))
Exception: Cannot find VBoxPython module (tried: VBoxPython3_8, VBoxPython3, VBoxPython)
```

I have found that these modules have to be in `/usr/lib/virtualbox`, which currently contains only these files:

```
$ ls /usr/lib/virtualbox/ | grep VBoxPython
VBoxPython2_7.so
VBoxPython3_7m.so
VBoxPython.so
```

These .so files are installed via the `virtualbox` package. However, I cannot manage to have neither `VBoxPython3.so` nor `VBoxPython3.8.so` by reinstalling. I have looked at the virtualbox code and it seems that the c macro `PY_VERSION_HEX` indicates 3.7 instead of 3.8, which would be caused by the wrong `Python.h` header being included.

How can I force virtualbox package to include `/usr/include/python3.8/Python.h` instead of `/usr/include/python3.7/Python.h` ?

Uninstalling python3.7 is not an option.

Comment: Have you tried creating virtual environment for python 3.8 and running?

Answer (score 2):

The [pyvbox package docs](https://github.com/sethmlarson/virtualbox-python) (redirected from `pyvbox`) imply that the `.so` files aren't installed by it. But, they do note that the Python package is dependent on the [VirtualBox SDK](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads). Which, in turn, recommend installing the SDK to the system Python manually. That latest seems irky, especially when done outside a package manager but maybe they know better.

Digging around, I found the `.so` files are owned by the OS package `virtualbox`. In other words, `virtualbox` must be installed with Python3.8 support.

```sh
# Who owns/provides this file (use your dist equivalent or duckduckgo)
$ yay -Fy /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxPython3_8.so
...
usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxPython3_8.so is owned by community/virtualbox 6.1.6-1
```

I suggest you reinstall the `virtualbox` package for your distribution. Installing the latest version will provide the latest `.so` library files `Virtualbox` supports.
Let's test the theory

```sh
# Install Virtualbox and the Virtualbox SDK
yay -S virtualbox virtualbox-sdk python-virtualbox

# Assert we aren't getting an error
$ python -c "import virtualbox; _vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox(); print('Success!')"
Success!
```

Otherwise, if the package doesn't include 3.8 support, you'll have to compile it yourself while making sure `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to your Python 3.8 dev libraries. But, I strongly recommend against this. It is infinitely better to work along with your package manager and benefit from upstream work.

Good luck!